# How can I get the highlight data from the index as a string or How can I print it out?

Tags: pandas, datetime, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

The data I am using is as follows:

[image: 1]

I would like to get the specific highlighted value and not sure about how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: Try this, `earthquakes.index.values`?

Comment: Its not working ;__;, I just want that one data

Comment: If you only want the first one: earthquakes.index.values[0]

Answer (score 0):

You could just do:

```py
print(earthquakes.index.values[0])
```